# Location element of customizable CV public view on StackOverflow Careers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

StackOverflow careers allows each user to customize the public view of their CV and show or hide various elements as the user sees fit.

One of the elements is "Location", underneath the "Personal Information" main heading.

The "Location" checkbox is broken in that despite it's checked (show) or unchecked (hide) setting, the location is always displayed on the public CV.

Can this please be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved, thanks for the heads-up. Would you try it again?

Comment: I can confirm that it's working for me here!  Thanks Matt!