# Careers 2.0 Profile Privacy - How to disagree?

Tags: discussion, jobs, privacy

> Update on Careers 2.0 Profiles:
>
> We've decided to discontinue a feature that allows Careers 2.0
>   candidates to mark individual fields of their profile as private. 
>   We've noticed that you're profile is currently designated as public,
>   but has at least one field marked private.  In order to be sure your
>   privacy is protected, we will be marking yours and all other profiles
>   that are using this feature as private by Friday, July 6th.

So how do we say "This is a really bad idea and I'm against it?"

Reasons:

I'd like my profile to be searchable, but I'm uncomfortable with everyone on the Internet knowing the details of my employment history.

In today's world "less control of our privacy" is not something I like.

**EDIT:** It appears there is already a feature request: [Please preserve the "customize public view" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/please-preserve-the-customize-public-view-feature)

Comment: Well I'd start by making a Feature Request tagged question stating you'd like this to be moved back to the old way. You're 50% there :P

Comment: I'd like to know what _is_ marked as private - I don't see an indicator on my profile.

Comment: @Oded It’s a legacy feature of Careers 1.0. If you used it during the early days of Stack Careers, we “grandfathered” the feature on your profile. If you created a profile since (approximately) spring of last year, or didn’t use it in the first place, you will never have seen it.

Comment: @MattSherman - That will explain why I never saw it...

Comment: Is this feature-to-be-axed different from the "customize public view" feature? Checking the boxes doesn't make something private, it makes it public, which sounds opposite from the feature described here. So, color me confused too. But please don't take away my "customize public view" feature.

Comment: Hear hear.  I agree completely and for the exact same reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)!

But first, the backstory:

A year ago, we quietly disabled this feature.  Anyone who had previously marked a field private still saw it, and everyone else never even saw the option<sup>1</sup>.  In one year, we've received **zero** requests for this.  Therefore, we concluded that this is an unnecessary feature.

We could definitely be wrong, but this has been off for basically a year.  In that time people have created tens of thousands of profiles and nobody missed it.

<sup>1 This is why so many people are saying "What? I don't even see this option?  Where is it?"</sup>

Comment: It appears there is already a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/please-preserve-the-customize-public-view-feature

Comment: "In one year, we've received zero requests for this." That doesn't mean that people wouldn't use it if it was available. Odds are good, the people who wouldn't accept certain things to be public simply didn't create a public profile at all. And some people would have preferred to keep things private but decided the benefits outweighed the drawbacks. Basically now, you're forcing those people who would have been in group A to decide if they want to continue having a public profile at all. You're taking something away from them that they value.

Comment: What, exactly, was disabled a year ago?  I've had a SO Careers profile for quite a while and I have always been able to mark elements of my CV and effectively hidden from public view using the "Customize public view" functionality.  I can still do that to this very day.  I even filed a [bug regarding the location being broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120244/57477) earlier this year!

Comment: @CraigTP it was disabled for all new users and for any old user who wasn't making use of it

Comment: @DavidFullerton - So I still have the functionality as I was an "old" user and _was_ (and still am) making use of it?  Hmm.  There's a case-in-point right there for why it should stay!  :)